# Dual monitor (vga) doesn`t work

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, vga

After upgrading OS, from Ubuntu 16 LTS to 18 LTS, second monitor plugged on vga stop to work.
I`m using nvidia-driver-390.
I tested cable and monitor with other laptop and working without any issue.

The solutions posted on [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035680/dual-monitor-using-intel-graphics-stopped-to-work-on-ubuntu-18-04) doesn't work for me.

How to fix it?
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: What does your xorg folder look like, all randr does its help to set vga in your xorg file, out of date drivers aren't out of date if you allow the monitor through

Comment: Purge and reinstall nVidia driver might help. You might try it https://askubuntu.com/questions/628494/how-to-reset-ubuntu-to-default-display-settings-after-failed-nvidia-driver-insta

Comment: The issue was solved here [https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1035768/linux/ubuntu-18-04-can-t-see-second-monitor/]. I deleted /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf than I edited /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf and
added 
Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes".